# Solve: $z^6-(-1-i)^3=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$z^6-(-1-i)^3=0$$

$$z^6=(-1-i)^3$$

$$z^6=(1-3i-3+i)$$

$$z^6=(-2-2i)$$

$$-2-2i: \text{  }r=\sqrt{(-2)^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{8}\text{  , }\theta=arctan(1)-\pi=-\frac{3}{4}\pi$$

(Why for $x<0,y<0,arctan(\frac{y}{x})-\pi$ and for $x<0,y>0,arctan(\frac{y}{x})+\pi$?)

$$z^6=\sqrt{8}cis(-\frac{3}{4}\pi)$$

$$z_{i}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis(\frac{-\frac{3}{4}\pi+2\pi k}{6})\text{ ,} k=\{0,1,2,...,5\}$$

$$z_{0}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis-\frac{\pi}{8}$$

$$z_{1}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis-\frac{5\pi}{24}$$

$$z_{2}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis-\frac{13\pi}{24}$$

$$z_{3}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis-\frac{7\pi}{8}$$

$$z_{4}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis-\frac{29\pi}{24}$$

$$z_{5}={8}^\frac{1}{12}cis-\frac{37\pi}{24}$$

Are the stages correct? is there a shorter way/approch to solve this?

Comment: Faster ways may or may not involve seeing what you wrote faster, but I can't think of much off the top of my head.

Comment: Are you just seeking the 6th roots of $$-(2+2i)$$?

Comment: We need dxiv to solve this. !!!

Comment: You could do $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and you get a quadratic and a biquadratic, though not sure if it's better

Comment: As for your $\arctan$ question, $\arctan$ can only ever give you a number between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, which is to say $x>0$. If you have $x<0$, you will have to add or subtract $\pi$ to whatever $\arctan$ gives you. Whether you have to add or subtract is really up to you, but the rules you are given fits if you want all your angles between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. If you like your angles between $0$ and $2\pi$ instead, you should always add $\pi$ (and add $2\pi$ if we have $x>0, y<0$).

Comment: @Arthur but when I need to add or subtract $\pi$? I know that it is with regard to $(x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to $z^6-w^3=0$ or $(\dfrac{z^2}{w})^3=1$, where $w = -1-i.$ This will be slightly easier to write down since it is very easy to describe the third roots of unity, which are $1, \omega, \omega^2$ with $\omega = \cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Shouldn't we write the unknown $z$ on one side? as $\frac{z^2}{w}=\frac{z^2}{-1-i}$ can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ gbox The solution below gives perfectly detailed answer as well. Mine can be completed by solving $z^2=w, z^2=w\omega$ and $z^2=w\omega^2$ separately. It looks like you know how to solve these equations, based on what you wrote in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(-i-1) = \sqrt{2}e^{i \frac{5\pi}{4}}$,  and $(-i-1)^3 = 2^{3/2}e^{i \frac{15\pi}{4}}=2^{3/2}e^{i \frac{7\pi}{4}}$. Let $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$, so we are looking for solutions to 
$$
|z|^6 e^{i6\theta} = 2^{3/2}e^{i \frac{7\pi}{4}}.
$$
We must have $|z|=2^{1/4}$ and $6\theta = \frac{7}{4}\pi + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$. For $k=0,1,2,3,4,5$, we have that 
$$
2^{1/4} e^{i\frac{7+8k}{24}\pi}
$$
are all solutions.